# Problem with a floating point value in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point

I'm having a problem with a floating point value conversion. I have a private property in a class with a value of 317.46. If I multiply this value by 100, I should have the value of 317.46, and that's what seems to be happening, but when i use json_encode it returns another value, slightly smaller. This is the result from the debug console:

```
$this->valor
317.46
$this->valor * 100
31746
json_encode($this->valor * 100)
"31745.99999999999996"
```

I known this is due to the way floating points are stored, but in this case I need it to be 'rendered' as a integer, otherwise it will generate an error in the API I'm calling. In other languages I would convert it to a int value, or use a `decimal` datatype, like in `c#`, but it's not available in PHP as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `round()` to remove the round-off error from floating point representation.

```
echo json_encode(round($this->valor * 100))
```

If this is money, it's a good idea to use pennies as the representation in the first place, to avoid problems from converting to and from decimal fractions.